# show https url in gitlab behind load balancer

Tags: git, gitlab

I am running gitlab behind a load balancer which is handle my SSL. I have gitlab running as non SSL and the load balancer handlles the https connections. my question is how can I get the path to the repository in the "Activity" section to show https instead of http? The users may be confused when it is showing http but the correct url is https.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a "perfect" solution, but what I did is, I set the `external_url` in the `gitlab.rb` config file to HTTPS and added the following lines to the nginx configuration (`/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf`) **manually**:

```
location / {
  ...

  proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
  proxy_set_header    X-Url-Scheme        https;

  ...
}
```

After restarting Gitlab with `gitlab-ctl restart` everything worked for me. Be aware that with the next `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` these changes will be lost.

Currently I don't know how to add the required nginx configuration directly to the `gitlab.rb` configuration.

Comment: how is the external url configured on gitlab.rb?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it [docs: supporting proxied ssl](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#supporting-proxied-ssl).

From the docs:

> By default NGINX will auto-detect whether to use SSL if external_url contains https://. If you are running GitLab behind a reverse proxy, you may wish to terminate SSL at another proxy server or load balancer. To do this, be sure the external_url contains https:// and apply the following configuration to gitlab.rb:

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}
```

I also added proxy headers in my nginx server block:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://...;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
}
```